# why this line blocks my app

Tags: iphone, video

In my `viewDidLoad` method I have the following lines:

```
    NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video1" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSString *path2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video2" ofType:@"mp4"];

    MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer1 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1]];
    MPMoviePlayerController *videoPlayer2 = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path2]];

    UIImage *thumbnail1 = [videoPlayer1 thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    UIImage *thumbnail2 = [videoPlayer2 thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

in this state my app gets blocked when this class is accessed.If I remove these two lines it works great:

```
    UIImage *thumbnail1 = [videoPlayer1 thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
    UIImage *thumbnail2 = [videoPlayer2 thumbnailImageAtTime:1.0 timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

it works just fine.So I'm working on ios 4 and I have the videos.What could be wrong?Thanks

EDIT: I have this in my console: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'`

Comment: I don't think your exception is linked to the posted code (there are no mutable arrays involved). You should check that your paths and video players are not nil. Also note that although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time can play its movie.

Comment: but I'm not playing any of those movies.I just want a thumbnailImageAtTime image from the video.

Answer (score 1):

The MPMoviePlayerController API is asynchronous and I don't believe it could get thumbnails for you until it's loaded the movie. You can register for the MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification notifications and check if the moviePlayer loadState is MPMovieLoadStatePlayable. Be careful the load state is a bit mask so use bitwise operators:

```
if (moviePlayer.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlayable)
    // get the thumbnail
```

not

```
if (moviePlayer.loadState == MPMovieLoadStatePlayable)
    // get the thumbnail
```

Or you can use the

```
- (void)requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:(NSArray *)playbackTimes timeOption:(MPMovieTimeOption)option
```

method and you will get MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification notifications when the thumbnails are ready.